# Importing rows from CSV not importing properly

Tags: .net, vb.net

I hope you all had a pleasant weekend!

I am currently trying to import CSV files to a dataset.tables("CSVImportedFile"). Here is my code:

```
    Dim ImportCSV As New OpenFileDialog
    With ImportCSV
        .Title = "Import CSV File"
        .Filter = "PowerBI (*.csv)|*.csv"
    End With

    If ImportCSV.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
        Dim CSVPath As String = ImportCSV.FileName
        Dim CSVDirectory As String = Path.GetDirectoryName(CSVPath) & "\"
        Dim CSVFile As String = Path.GetFileName(CSVPath)

        Using ImportConnection As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0;Data Source=" & CSVDirectory & ";Extended Properties=""Text;HDR=YES;""")
            Using ImportAdapter As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [" & CSVFile & "]", ImportConnection)
                Try
                    ImportAdapter.Fill(dset.Tables("CSVImportedFile"))
                Catch ex As Exception
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
                End Try
                ImportConnection.Close()
            End Using
        End Using

        For Each CSVRows As DataRow In dset.Tables("CSVImportedFile").Rows
            'Trying to find the ID within the dataset column "TempID"
            Dim FindID As Integer = ourBindingSource.Find("TempID", CSVRows(0).ToString)

            Debug.Print FindID.ToString() & " " & ourBindingSource.Find("TempID", CSVRows(0).ToString)

            If FindID < 0 Then
                'If TemplateID does not exist
                ourBindingSource.AddNew()
            End If

            'Setting all checkboxes to indeterminate
            chkBox1.CheckState = CheckState.Indeterminate
            chkBox2.CheckState = CheckState.Indeterminate
            chkBox3.CheckState = CheckState.Indeterminate
            chkBox4.CheckState = CheckState.Indeterminate
            chkBox5.CheckState = CheckState.Indeterminate
            chkBox6.CheckState = CheckState.Indeterminate
            chkBox7.CheckState = CheckState.Indeterminate
            chkBox8.CheckState = CheckState.Indeterminate
            chkBox9.CheckState = CheckState.Indeterminate
            chkBox10.CheckState = CheckState.Indeterminate
            chkBox11.CheckState = CheckState.Indeterminate
            chkBox12.CheckState = CheckState.Indeterminate


            CType(ourBindingSource.Current, DataRowView)("TempID") = CSVRows(0).ToString
            If CSVRows(3).ToString = "Section 1" Then
                chkBox1.CheckState = CheckState.Checked
            ElseIf CSVRows(3).ToString = "Section 2" Then
                chkBox2.CheckState = CheckState.Checked
            ElseIf CSVRows(3).ToString = "Section 3" Then
                chkBox3.CheckState = CheckState.Checked
            ElseIf CSVRows(3).ToString = "Section 4" Then
                chkBox4.CheckState = CheckState.Checked
            ElseIf CSVRows(3).ToString = "Section 5" Then
                chkBox5.CheckState = CheckState.Checked
            ElseIf CSVRows(3).ToString = "Section 6" Then
                chkBox6.CheckState = CheckState.Checked
            End If
        Next
    End If
```

Here is what my CSV looks like in a nutshell:

```
ID      SectionNumber
800     Section 1
800     Section 2
800     Section 4
800     Section 6
800     Section 3
800     Section 5
853     Section 3
853     Section 2
853     Section 1
853     Section 4
879     Section 2
879     Section 3
879     Section 4
879     Section 6
879     Section 5
```

So what is ***supposed*** to happen is that we search for the ID. If it doesn't already exist we are adding a new row via our BindingSource and then adjusting our checkboxes as necessary. If it ***does*** exist, then we do the same thing, except we don't add a new row.

What is actually happening though, is that not only are the checkboxes not appropriately marked off, but there are duplicate (always in twos) rows. So the rows that are added to my dataset looks like this:
800
800
853
853
879
879
When in reality it should look like this:
800
853
879
I'm so confused! Does anyone know what's going on?

**EDIT:** 

Here is the following output looks like:

```
Debug.Print FindID.ToString() & " " & ourBindingSource.Find("TempID", CSVRows(0).ToString)
```

```
-1 -1
-1 -1
0 0
0 0
0 0
0 0
-1 -1
-1 -1
2 2
2 2
-1 -1
-1 -1
4 4
4 4
4 4
```

**EDIT 2: My ourBindingSource**

```
Dim dataset As New DataSet
WithEvents ourBindingSource As New BindingSource
'Dim ourBindingSource As New BindingSource
Dim ourDataView As New DataView

ourDataView = dataset.Tables("DefaultView").DefaultView
ourBindingSource.DataSource = ourDataView
DGV_blk.DataSource = ourBindingSource

'The sections are the SQL table headers
chkBox1.DataBindings.Add("CheckState", ourBindingSource, "Section1", True, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation, CheckState.Indeterminate)
chkBox2.DataBindings.Add("CheckState", ourBindingSource, "Section2", True, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation, CheckState.Indeterminate)
chkBox3.DataBindings.Add("CheckState", ourBindingSource, "Section3", True, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation, CheckState.Indeterminate)
chkBox4.DataBindings.Add("CheckState", ourBindingSource, "Section4", True, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation, CheckState.Indeterminate)
chkBox5.DataBindings.Add("CheckState", ourBindingSource, "Section5", True, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation, CheckState.Indeterminate)
chkBox6.DataBindings.Add("CheckState", ourBindingSource, "Section6", True, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation, CheckState.Indeterminate)
```

**Edit 3: My suspicions**
Okay so after some more tinkering I still haven't gotten anywhere with this, but I suspect that it's because when it adds a new record, it doesn't commit it. Could this have anything to do with dirty edits?

Comment: Find() is that supposed to return a 1, 0 or -1 or True or False?

Comment: Hi Michael, it seems to return -1 to a non -1 number. -1 for an ID that does not exist.

Comment: you need to debug your code, see how many times it loops.  use Debug.Print FindID.ToString*() & " " & ourBindingSource.Find("TempID", CSVRows(0).ToString)

Comment: Mmm...Sorry Michael, I'm still a little new to coding and haven't used Debug.Print before. But I'm getting an "Expression Expected" error at FindID.ToString*(). I think meant FindID.ToString() right? (no sarcasm, honest question) I ran that...but don't know where I'm supposed to see what it output. My Output Debug screen doesn't seem to display anything useful.

Comment: Sorry, it wouldn't let me edit my comment. I got the output working. It seems to be looping the correct number of times: one for each row. But it sees -1 for the first two rows for each ID and then a non -1 number for the rest of the rows for that ID. I'll update my original post to show what it looks like.

Comment: just do "select distinct *"  i have no idea what your source is doing.

Comment: Sorry - may I ask what is confusing to you? I'm probably explaining this all very poorly...Basically the code is supposed to loop through a CSV sheet. The first column is the ID, but there are multiple entries for each ID - all with different information. If the ID doesn't already exist in my DGV, then it is added. The issue here is that it is added twice when the ID doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it! I just needed to add `.EndEdit` to my `BindingSource`.

Answer (score 0):

should you not be looking for

```
ourBindingSource.Find("ID", CSVRows(0).ToString)
```

not TempID

Comment: Hi Michael! No - I have my dataset column 1 lableled TEMPID. So what that line of code is doing is searching that column for a match in CSVRows(0) to see if the TEMPID exists in CSVRows. If so, then just rewrite the info to that row. If not, then addnew and then write the info.

Comment: ourBindingSource.Find("TempID", CSVRows(0).ToString)  this is not returning 800 per your first recordset or debug statement

Comment: Well, that line isn't supposed to return 800 in the debug statement. It's supposed to return -1 for rows that don't exist, but you can see it returns -1 twice even though we've added the entry after the first time it returned -1 for the ID. ourBindingSource.Find("ID", CSVRows(0).ToString) isn't going to do anything since "ID" doesn't exist as a column within my DataSet.

Comment: why dont you do "distinct *" in your select statement.

Comment: can i see the rest of your code where outBindingSource is made?

Comment: Can't do distinct because the way the CSV sheet is made created (not by me, it's an automated process), there are multiple duplicate ID rows that contain different information.